# Insert from table a to table b where records in a don't exist in b

Tags: sql, database

**I have two tables with the same schemas, table A and table B:**

```
| Table [A]        | Table [B]   
| id    value      | id    value
| 1     15         | 1     19
| 2     18         | 3     28
| 5     22         | 4     39
```

**I would like to do:**

```
insert into a select * from b where [b.id not exists in a]
```

**Question:** What's the syntax for this - in particular, the portion in the brackets?

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Ingres Vectorwise, so was looking for basic SQL, nothing too fancy :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use `INSERT INTO..SELECT` statement and `LEFT JOIN`.

```
INSERT INTO tableB (id, Value)
SELECT  a.id, a.value
FROM    tableA a
        LEFT JOIN tableB b 
            ON a.ID = b.ID
WHERE   b.id IS NULL
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b56d8d/1)

Answer (score 4):

Like so:

```
INSERT INTO a(id, value)
SELECT * 
FROM b 
WHERE b.id NOT IN (SELECT id from a)
  AND b.id IS NOT NULL ;
```

**Note that:** You have to watch out the `NULL` values, when using the predicate `IN`. Otherwise use the `NOT EXISTS` predicate, it is safer, or using a `LEFT JOIN` like what @kuyaJohn suggested.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on SQL 2008 + you could also use a merge to achieve this, giving you the advantage of being able to easily add conditions for not only where rows don't exist in the target table, but also what to do if the IDs match but the value is different (update maybe) or if there is a row in the target table that doesn't exist in the source (delete maybe):

```
MERGE TableB AS TARGET
USING TableA AS SOURCE
ON (target.ID = source.ID) 

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
    THEN INSERT (ID, Value) VALUES (source.ID, source.Value);
```

More information on using merge can be found here:

[Inserting, Updating, and Deleting Data by Using MERGE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522522%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)